# How to convert Text file to ByteArray and send it via API using NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a text file. I have to convert it to byteArray and send it through REST API. How to achieve this?

I tried many ways to convert the file to byteArray, last one is ExecuteScript with below code:

```
import base64
import codecs

with codecs.open('/path/to/input/file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
file_content = file.read()
file_bytes = file_content.encode('utf-8')
encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(file_bytes)
encoded_string = encoded_bytes.decode('utf-8')

flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'fileContent', encoded_string)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

but still get error:

> utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: unexpected code byte in <script> at line number 6

REST API Config:

```
HTTP Method: POST
API URL:.....
Request Content-Type: application/octet-stream

authentication User: username
authentication password: password
```

we applied it in VB.net as below:

```
Function CallApi(APIURL As String,filepath As String) As String
Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(APIURL)
Dim txtfile = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath"file.txt")
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications
req.Headers("Authorization") = "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes("username:password"))
req.Method = "POST"
req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Dim byteArray As Byte() = txtfile
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
' response
Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
Dim s As Stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8)
Dim doc As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
Return doc
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard processors:

`FetchFile` - to read file from specified path into nifi flowfile content

`InvokeHTTP` - make http request with flowfile content